# Delete worksheet when unmodified for XXX amount of time

Tags: vba, excel

Question:
**Is there a way that I can either delete a worksheet that hasn't been modified for 'X' number of days? Or transfer that inactive page from our active workbook into an archive book?**

I'm working on a project that takes all the active worksheets (generated from job #) and summarizes the contained data. The worksheet names are all variable and generated based on data filled into a master sheet.

Once a job is completed, that worksheet will probably never need to be accessed again.

I appreciate any insight!

Comment: You could create a seperate sheet where you track the last changed date for a worksheet within the book and then create a macro that does what you need to do based on the date difference. Excel does not track this info by itself, only for the Workbook as a whole (the last change date in Windows) - A little more elaboration on what you've tried so far is welcome, so we can give some actual pointers from where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Yes. Use a change event on the sheet and when it's been modified write the current timestamp to another sheet that can be hidden in the backgroud. On startup, or whenever you want, loop through the sheets containing the timestamp and delete/move if the date is greater than whatever difference you want is

Comment: Indeed, like Tom said: You can update said time stamps on the Worksheet_Change event. The sheet with the time stamps itself can be set to ws.visible = xlSheetVeryHidden to hide it from users altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this in your `ThisWorkbook` object. It will update the tracker sheet (`Sheet1` here) on any change done in any sheet on the workbook. Then on start, if the date difference is greater then a week a go, it will (when uncommented) delete the sheet. Change this if you want to do something different

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim DayDiff As Long
    Dim c

    DayDiff = 7
    ' Update this to the sheet that you want to keep your timestamp list
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each c In rng
            If c.Offset(0, 1) < Now() - DayDiff Then
                Debug.Print c
                'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c.Value2).Delete
                'Range(c, c.Offset(0, 1)).Delete
            End If
        Next c
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c
    ' Update this to the sheet that you want to keep your timestamp list
    With Sheet1
        If Not sh.Name = .Name Then
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
            Set c = rng.Find(sh.Name)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                c.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
            Else
                With .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
                    .Value2 = sh.Name
                    .Offset(0, 1) = Now()
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Small addendum: It doesn't keep track of altering sheet names and a name change on the worksheet does not trigger the event you're hooking into. If that's an additional requirement, you'd need a wrapper class to update the tracking sheet with the altering sheet names, since otherwise they won't be found and thus not deleted.
Other than that an elegant solution.

Comment: No it doesn't but I didn't want to do all the work for them ;)

Comment: Yeah fair enough. :) haha

Comment: Very cool! I'll good around with this and it should do exactly what I want it to do! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry, one thing I'm stuck on: is there any way to exclude pages from this count? I don't want to accidently delete my master, template, email form, dump page. Is there something I can plug in to exclude those constant names? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah where it says `If Not sh.Name = .Name Then` Add your sheets that you don't want deleted in there with an `Or` statement. e.g. `If Not sh.Name = .Name Or sh.Name = "Master" Then`